# Store the content of a file returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I am trying to store all the content of a file in `allFileData` but it always has a null value
when the function returns.

I tried several things but none worked, any ideas?

```
const linereader = require("line-reader");

async function getFileData(filePath) {
   let allFileData = "";

   await linereader.eachLine(filePath, function (line, last, complete) {
     allFileData += `${line}\n`;
   });

  return allFileData;
}
```

Comment: I am assuming eachLine does not return a promise My guess is you will not be able to use await. https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-reader#promises

Comment: @epascarello Even if I stop using async await it has the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation of line-reader:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-reader#promises

https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader/blob/master/lib/line_reader.js

There are two problems with your code:

1. The function `eachLine` does not return anything hence also not a Promise. Thus, as mentioned in the comments, `await` does not do anything on your code and your function returns the initial value of `allFileData` which is an empty string.
   (Be aware that you are using a callback for reading the lines which is asynchronous. Thus, the reading is not finished when you reach the return statement.)
2. If you specify the third parameter - `complete` in your case the function behaves differently according to the above linked documentation than you expect. Furthermore, as you do not use the parameter in your callback function, it is better to omit it.

The following code will help you get started - it prints each line to the console. You only have to adapt the callback function or convert the result to a promise as pointed out in the linked documentation.

```js
const linereader = require("line-reader");

function getFileData(filePath) {
   linereader.eachLine(filePath, function (line, last) {
    if (last) {
        return false;
    }
     console.log(line);
   });
}
```